# How to get matplotlib working in Python3 on OS X?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, error-handling

I am trying to do Google's deep learning course on Udemy. For assignment one I need to verify that the following modules are working on my machine, but can't get matplotlib.pyplot working. The python code I must get to compile is the following:

```
# These are all the modules we'll be using later. Make sure you can import them
# before proceeding further.
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
import tarfile
from IPython.display import display, Image
from scipy import ndimage
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlretrieve
from six.moves import cPickle as pickle

# Config the matplotlib backend as plotting inline in IPython
%matplotlib inline
```

When I compile and run this like so:

```
python3.6 nn_assignment_1.py
```

I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nn_assignment_1.py", line 9, in <module>
    from IPython import display, Image
ImportError: cannot import name 'Image'
```

Any ideas how to get matplotlib working for python 3 here? I have been banging my head against the keyboard for hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: It seems to have stalled on numpy - can you pip install that first?

Comment: thanks, that worked, now have another error i edited the question to contain.